# How to use a file url from Advanced Custom Fields to overwrite post title link?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I am developing a custom post type for the client to be able to upload a pdf using the advanced custom field file type. The current theme is Avada and I am wondering how I can change the title link to be the file URL?

I have thought about creating a custom page template and disregarding the archive altogether. I am open to suggestions/ideas.

The ideal outcome is using the native archive layout but having the title link to the file URL (pdf) instead of to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the filter to modify the title. The below code is untested just giving you the idea. Also, Make sure to check if the custom field exist. 
   add_filter('the_title', 'my_custom_title_with_link');

```
function my_custom_title_with_link($title){
    global $post;
    //please do a check for the post type otherwise all the post title will be changed
   $title = "<a href=".esc_url(get_field('custom_field')).">.$title.</a>";
   return $title; 
}
```